# Pass HTML form inputs to PHP and then to AJAX for JQPlot

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am a newbie in both HTML and JavaScript so, any detail example will be helpful. Basically, I am trying to display data plots and tables, based on selected values, using HTML form, PHP and JQPlot. Once the user submits the form, I want the graph to be displayed on a new page. The PHP script reads the user input to determine the appropriate data points and send them to JQPlot (via AJAX, I believe). The following are snippets of my HTML and PHP codes. The ValidateForm() checks to ensure that values are populated correctly and is working fine. For example purposes, I just used the loop in PHP to populate the array however, in reality, it will be populated from a DB.Thanks.

```
HTML:
 <form name="myForm" action="Test.php" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" method="post">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                    Analysis Level:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <select name="level" id="level" >
                                            <option value="first">First</option>
                                            <option value="second">Second</option>
                                            <option value="third">Third</option>
                                    </select>
                            </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                             --------
                      </tr>
                      <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
              </table>
    </form>

 Test.php:
  <html>
  <body>
  <?php
    $level = $_POST['level'];
    for($i=0;$i<$level;$i++)
       $Val[$i] = $i *2;
    echo json_encode($Val);
   ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: .. and where is your javascript apart from the inline onsubmit .. ?

Comment: what's your question?  You mention 2 different pages, a form, graph, db etc. Have no idea what part you need asssitance with

Comment: I need help with the javascript, ajax portion of the code. Thanks